# Redux-Saga takeEvery for multiple actions and one task

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I have a watcher similar to this

```
export default function* watch() {
    yield takeEvery(getProducts, fetchData)
    yield takeEvery(getUser, fetchData)
}
```

But in this form, it does not work, because fetchData must be run once and only if both getProducts and getUser succeeded

Is it possible to somehow transfer both actions to takeEvery, or is there an analogue of takeEvery, which can accept two or more actions and execute the fetchData function only after the successful execution of all the transferred actions?

Comment: Are `getProducts` and `getUser` [return a pattern](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api#takeeverypattern-saga-args)?

Comment: @Alex yes, they are return pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `all` in combination with `take` to wait for two actions regardless of order.

```
export default function* watch() {
    yield all([
        take(getProducts),
        take(getUser)
    ])
    yield call(fetchData)
}
```

In case you want to wait for these two actions again once the fetching is done you can wrap it a infinite while cycle:

```
export default function* watch() {
    while (true) {
        yield all([
            take(getProducts),
            take(getUser)
        ])
        yield call(fetchData) 
    }
}
```

You can also replace the `call` effect with `fork` if you don't want to wait for the fetching to be done before waiting for another pair of actions.